# using an electret microphone to trigger an LED

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design

I would simply like to trigger (on or off) an LED based on the pressure level at an electret microphone, much like a stroboscope. The circuit should be

1. as simple as possible (in terms of number of components) and
2. work also at low sound levels

After some research, I found a neat [circuit scheme from a](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwuGm1VLQXLgTWNnd0pvbnBvTFk/view) [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqhiYsnuwgQ). I built it and it worked fine, however it is not sensitive enough.

Now I simulated this circuit in LTSpice and tried to vary a few resistors to see whether I can tune the sensitivity. While increasing the Megaohm resistor makes the thing more sensitive, it also reduces the dynamic range for the diodes.

Since I am a beginner: what would be a nice way to improve said design, such that it works at low noise levels? At best, it would feature a potentiometer to tune the sensitivity...

[image: LTSpice circuit scheme (using a AC source instead of a mic)]

Comment: Google "led color organ" for better examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use an LM386 to amplify the audio from the microphone. You can use a potentiometer to adjust the gain of the output of that IC. But you would get an analog output so the LED would be dim at some points based on the amplitude of the input signal. You may want a comparator to define the point at which the LEDS turn on, which you could also use a potentiometer to bias to define the trigger point. Add a low pass filter before the amplifier. The 555 timer circuit would be fun to try out as well.

Comment: I did this in the end, because it was very easy to integrate into the circuit (no feedback, just the lm386 "in front of" Q1). worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The circuit works by biasing Q1 so that it keeps Q2 and Q3 cut off. When the microphone generates a negative pulse, the current through Q1 is reduced, its collector voltage rises, and Q2 and Q3 conduct current through the LEDs.

The simplest way to increase sensitivity is to increase the value of R2 until Q1 is *just barely* keeping Q2 and Q3 off. However, there will be limits on how well this works over a range of temperatures and battery voltages.

---

A better circuit would use something like a 555, which has a reasonably precise comparator on its input, and provides a well-defined output pulse each time it is triggered:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGgrkW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks Dave, I tried that in LTSpice and found that this, as you say, works only limited. Typically I cannot fully "switch" the LED at some point (I only achieve current variatls of 10% at the LED for low voltage levels at V1) or always off. Could I add e.g. another transistor to amplify the signal further?

Comment: you'd end up making your amplifier ever more complex. What about an opamp IC?

Comment: I need to stick to 9V, but I guess an OpAmp like LM324 could do the job?